# "Colpo di espresso" = "shot of espresso"?

Tags: translation, phrase-request, english-comparison

Does "shot of espresso" translate into Italian as "*colpo di caffé espresso*", or is there a different way of saying this, such as *tazza*?

Comment: There are so many words and tastes connected with coffee in Italy that perhaps a "colpo di (caffè) espresso" is a thing, somewhere. But I've never heard this..."espression": I would rather say a "tazza/tazzina di caffè" ("tazzina" being the smaller cup) or a "caffè ristretto" (short/concentrated) are more likely translations for "shot of coffee". Even "caffettino" might work, as an informal word suggesting a "small" coffee.

Comment: The idea of shot (a quick, single act of throwing  a small quantity of a drink into your mouth) is typical is strong liquors rather than coffe. You taste an expresso, rather than drink it.

Comment: As a native Italian speaker, I've never encountered the expression "_colpo di caffé espresso_" (please notice the Italian word is "_caffé_", with a double "_f_"). In general, we do not even specify "_espresso_" and simply say "_un caffé_" ("_espresso_" is implied, and we have to specify only if we do *not* want an espresso). For what concern the "shot", we use that term (in English) in reference to super alcoholic drinks but not for coffee. In conclusion, I'd translate "shot of espresso" with "_caffé *ristretto*_"

Comment: @ZabZonk, while I agree "_caffettino_" is informal, I'd say it is used as term of endearment rather than as diminutive and it suggests the idea of "well deserved" and/or "enjoyable" rather than "small".

Comment: “caffè” (with grave accent `, not *café, nor *caffé).

Comment: @secan. Apart for the accent, I agree with your comments. If you'll transform them into an answer, I'd upvote it!

Comment: Thanks @DaG; not for the upvote, but because I just learnt I've pronounced "_caffè_" in the wrong way for all my life. XD

Comment: @secan Totally agree: "caffettino" sounds endearing rather than a diminutive. I proposed it as a last ditch attempt at finding an alternative for "shot", which suggests chugging a single sip of a given beverage: and "caffettino" implies a very quick activity.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As a native Italian speaker, I've never encountered the expression "*colpo di caffè espresso*" (please notice the Italian word is "*caffè*", with a double "*f*"). In general, we do not even specify "*espresso*" and simply say "*un caffè*" ("*espresso*" is implied, and we have to specify only if we do **not** want an espresso). For what concerns the "shot", we use that term (in English) in reference to super alcoholic drinks but not for coffee. In conclusion, I'd translate "shot of espresso" with "*caffè **ristretto***"

While I agree the word "*caffettino*" (as suggested by @ZabZonk) is informal, I'd say it is used as term of endearment rather than as diminutive and it suggests the idea of "well deserved" and/or "enjoyable" rather than "small".